# How to make one shortcut to compile and execute cpp file

Tags: sudo, compiling, gcc, executable

I'm using Ubunru 15.04

GCC : 4.9.2

I usually use this command to compile my cpp files :

```
g++ /path/file.cpp -o /path/output
```

and it's cool ! so I made this into a shortcut with

```
.desktop
```

file format and make it executable and it works just fine !!

**now I need to make a single shortcut to compile the cpp file and run the output**

I simply tried :

```
g++ file.cpp -o output && /output
```

but this didn't work and giving **Permission Denied** when I try to run the .desktop file in terminal

```
ebram96@ebram96-jj:~$ '/path/shortcut.desktop' 
/path/shortcut.desktop: line 1: [Desktop: command not found
/path/shortcut.desktop: line 2: run: command not found
/path/shortcut.desktop: line 3: /path/file.cpp: Permission denied
```

here is my **.desktop** file :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=compile&run
Exec=g++ /path/code.cpp -o /path/output && /path/output
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

I simply tried :

```
g++ file.cpp -o output && ./output
```

I tried editing **/etc/sudoers** file adding these lines it also didn't work :

```
my_username ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/shortcut.desktop

my_username ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/

my_username ALL = NOPASSWD: /same_shortcut_path/output
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the desktop file. I've tested a simple C++ app and it works with this Exec property: `Exec=g++ /path/to/your/foo.cpp -o /path/to/your/output && /path/to/your/output`

Comment: @A.B. Done editing , I did what you mentioned in the comment and it didn't work giving the same result

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
cr(){
    if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
        echo "Usage: cr <file.cpp>"
    else
        name=$(echo $1 | cut -f 1 -d '.')
        g++ $1 -o name; ./name
    fi
}
```

This creates an alias that can be executed from the terminal.

The function name / command i.e. `cr` can be replaced if you wish.

To execute run: `cr file.cpp`

Answer (score 0):

You can't start a desktop file in this way. Move your desktop file into `~/.local/share/applications` and use `gtk-launch` or start it via Unity/GNOME Shell ...

```
gtk-launch shortcut     # without any path or extension
```

---

In your case, an alias would be the better solution

Open your `.profile` in an editor

```
nano ~/.profile
```

add a line like this

```
alias compile="g++ /path/to/your/foo.cpp -o /path/to/your/output && /path/to/your/output"
```

logout and re-login or use

```
source ~/.profile
```

Use the command (alias) with a simple

```
compile
```

Comment: it didn't work , after moving the shortcut to the mentioned directory and trying to launch : gtk-launch shortcut , it didn't work ,, I must open the terminal and use source ~/.profile and compile to make it work , I only want a single shortcut to compile and run without manually opening the terminal :(

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: there is nothing appears , but i think it is giving the same result because it does the same behavior ( only a terminal appears for a very little while and disappears) and the result of that i think it is "Permission Denied"

Comment: I also tried to make a shortcut for : source ~/.profile && compile but it is "Permission Denied" , I did a restart and log-off

Comment: No. Open your profile settings for your profile in gnome-terminal, go to the tab `Command` and select `Hold the terminal open` for `When command exits`. But as I said, the desktop file is the wrong way in your case.

Comment: No one said you have to start `source ~/.profile && compile`. `source ~/.profile` rereads the settings and you have to start the alias with `compile`

Comment: this is what appears after holding the terminal : The child process exited normally with status 1. // I don't understand your past comment ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a bash function (to add in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`):

```
function run-c++ {
  if ! type "g++" > /dev/null; then
    sudo apt-get install g++
  fi
  g++ $1 -o /tmp/main.out && chmod +x /tmp/main.out && /tmp/main.out
}
```

Then you can run `run-c++ ./whatever-path/to/program.cpp`.